# How to delete several object/field in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete part of the data stored in a document in a mongoDB (see example below), the data that I want to remove all "task-variables" (it is not an array) and some of the documents contains thousands of them.

DATA:

```json
{
    "Id": "1",
    "referenceId": "A001",
    "createdAt": "2023-04-25T11:08:06.384Z",
    "data": {
        "errors": {
            "archive": {
                "data": {
                    "A1": {
                        "name": "Error",
                        "stamp": "2023-04-25T11:08:10.700Z",
                        "task-variables": {
                            "taskErrorMessage": null,
                            "nrOfActiveInstances": 1,
                            "errorCode": "error-archiving"
                        }
                    },
                    "A2": {
                        "name": "Error",
                        "stamp": "2023-04-25T11:08:10.700Z",
                        "task-variables": {
                            "taskErrorMessage": null,
                            "nrOfActiveInstances": 1,
                            "errorCode": "error-archiving"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the example below, but it doesn't work. How can I remove/delete it?

```
db.getCollection("my-collection").updateOne(
   { referenceId: "A001" },
   { $unset: { "data.errors.archive.data.$**.task-variables": "" } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection("my-collection").updateOne(
  { referenceId: "A001" },
  { $unset: { "data.errors.archive.data.A1.task-variables": "", "data.errors.archive.data.A2.task-variables": "" } }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I require to remove it from thousand of objects, can not write manually all of them.  

A1,A2,......An

Comment: You can use the positional $[ ] with $unset to remove "task-variables" field from all subdocuments within the "data.errors.archive.data" 
like so: 
{ $unset: { "data.errors.archive.data.$[].task-variables": "" } }

Comment: It doesn't work. As you can see from the example, data.errors.archive.data is not an array

Comment: Your right, sorry for the confusion.
Have you tried to use the * wildcard character instead of $**? like this:
{ $unset: { "data.errors.archive.data.*.task-variables": "" } }

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work either